# What information is lost due to normalization?

Tags: normalization

Normalization is usually seen as a good thing for data preprocessing before training a model.

But I am wondering if there are some information in the data that might be lost during this process.

The analogy is convolutional neural networks vs feedforward neural network. Using a regular feedforward neural network for image classification requires collapsing an image into a single column vector. This causes a loss of spatial information in images.

I am wondering if normalization used in data preprocessing (e.g., StandardScaler) also causes some information loss and should not be used in certain situations.

Comment: Well yes, you lose the original scale of the variable, for ex. mean and SD.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization (or linear transforms in general, e.g. standardization) does not incur loss of information except the original min/max/mean/std etc..  An analog is converting between meters and centimeters - as far as you remember 1m = 100cm, then you can revert it.

Usually throwing the mean etc. away is OK as most likely it does not matter how far 2 samples are apart in absolute sense, but *relatively*. This is evidential from the fact that tree-based models (decision tree, random forest, XGBoost etc.) generally performs well on tabular data, yet being *scale-invariant* - they do not care about feature scale at all. This is unlike spatial position in image recognition which is crucial to the recognize an object.

By the way, occasionally a beginner would try different normalization scales e.g. 0-10, -1-+1, train a few models, gets different result and argues that something call **'contrast'** is lost in normalization. This is wrong.

The actual reason is usually due to 2 things - gradient descent and algorithm assumptions. Gradient descent comes with some hyperparameters e.g. learning rate. For different setup (scale, data, cost function) you have to try different parameters to find the best fit. Wrong parameters e.g. too high/low learning rate can lead to increasing loss/trap in local minima.

Another thing that may go wrong is that some preprocessing steps/models have implicit assumptions on feature's distribution, e.g. PCA (assume centered features) and Gaussian Mixture model (assume Gaussian), so watch out.

Answer (score -1):

Normalization doesn't actually lose any information, since it's only scaling the variable into the rage from 0 to 1 or -1 to 1. But there could be few cases which could be affected:

- When we normalize a variable, it discards some details about the original scale which might have some meaningful information.

For example, suppose you have a dataset of grayscale images where pixel values range from 0 to 255. If you normalize these pixel values to be between 0 and 1, you're essentially reducing the contrast in your images.

Now imagine that there are certain features in your images that can only be distinguished at higher contrasts - for instance, subtle differences in shading that distinguish one object from another. By normalizing the pixel values (and thereby reducing contrast), those features might become indistinguishable.

In this case, even though normalization doesn't technically "lose" any data (since it's just rescaling it), it does lose important information about contrasts and shades which were crucial for distinguishing certain features in the image.

- Normalization(MinMaxScalar) or Standardization(StandardScaler) is highly sensitive to outliers so if there are extreme outlier values in your dataset, these can skew the normalized results so that most 'normal' data points appear very close together.
- A common issue could be after normalization, features will be on different scales than originally measured which may make interpretation less intuitive, especially when communicating findings with non-data scientists. It could not be the problem all the time if you are not dealing with Stakeholders or SMEs.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. How does normalization reduce contrast?

Comment: Suppose you apply some normalization that compresses all pixel intensities towards a mean or median value, regardless of their initial differences. In that case, this could effectively reduce contrast because it minimizes variations among pixels which define contrasts in images. E.g. If we force all pixels' intensity to be around average value i.e., around ~125 (which may correspond to ~0.49 after scaling down), irrespective of whether they were closer to black or white originally. Then such operation would indeed lower down contrasts, making everything appear more similar/grayish than before.

Comment: No this is wrong. The relative difference between each pixel pair is preserved regardless of scaling and shifting, so there is no change in contrast from an algorithmic point of view. Think about the whole world of CV models which do normalization - if a property as important as contrast is lost, how on earth can they ever work?

Comment: Try it with a fixed range and you can see the difference. Try it with the range from 0 to 0.10

Comment: That difference is to naked eyes only, not to ML models.

Comment: Put it this way: do we lose anything by saying "the 2 dogs are 1 meters away" vs. "the 2 dogs are 100 centimeters away"?

Comment: In this case, you are right. But actually I got different results when I was modelling. This is why I was so confident. I was working on material science data and the images were drawn by hand, so I wanted every pixel where there is a straight line. And when I used standardization, I actually lost the straight line and it affected my results. This is why I am sure that this does make difference.

Comment: but this difference is not due to contrast.

Comment: Actually, in my case, it was due to contrast. Since multiple lines are overlapping on each other, so I was rooting on to the contrast and found out that it was happening because I was normalizing it in a smaller range. But if I normalize it over the bigger range like -1 to 1 then it won't be an issue.

Comment: Then this is not due to contrast, but normalization scale. Contrast stays the same.